# Trying to get the id to link to take to the next page

Tags: php

I am trying to get data from the link from this code and get an error as show below, what could be the problem with line 3 of the code?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<a href=\"edit_employee.php?$row['employee_id_passport']\">" . $row['first_name'] ." " . $row['surname'] . "</a>";

        echo "<br />";
    }
```

The error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /Library/WebServer/Documents/practice/employee/view_employee.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove single quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"edit_employee.php?$row[employee_id_passport]\">" . $row['first_name'] ." " . $row['surname'] . "</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you have 2 ways to resolve your request :

```
echo "<a href=\"edit_employee.php?{$row['employee_id_passport']}\">" . $row['first_name'] ." " . $row['surname'] . "</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href=\"edit_employee.php?" . $row['employee_id_passport'] . "\">" . $row['first_name'] ." " . $row['surname'] . "</a>";
```

or using single quote to avoid escaping double quote

```
echo '<a href="edit_employee.php?' . $row['employee_id_passport'] . '">' . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'] . '</a>';
```

Using `$row[employee_id_passport]` will produce a notice in error-log because `employee_id_passport` is interpreted as a constant.

Have a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) , first Note.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the single quotes or use { } braces e.g.

```
{$row['employee_id_passport']}
```

Check the manual on variable parsing:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex